# SQL convert data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two column with "text" datatype, i need to convert the the entire data in the first column to "datetime" data type, and the second column to "decimal(10,3)" data type.

Example of the current data:
first column: `20090901000005`  covert to `2009/08/01 00:00:05`
second column: `.125` convert to `00.125`

Any one can help Please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
select cast(cast(col1 as varchar(8)) as datetime) + 
  cast(left(right(cast(col1 as varchar(14)), 6), 2) + ':' +
  substring(right(cast(col1 as varchar(14)), 6), 2, 2) + ':' +
  right(right(cast(col1 as varchar(14)), 6), 2) as datetime)  newDate,
  cast(cast(col2 as varchar(10)) as decimal(10, 3)) newDecimal
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb540/30)

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an error, the SQL fiddle shows it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left and right to split string into parts. Then use convert function to convert it to date. ODBC canonical (120) format is: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss

```
CONVERT(datetime, 
    left( firstcol, 4 ) + '-' +
    left( right( firstcol, 10 ) ,2 ) + '-' +
    left( right( firstcol,  8 ) ,2 ) + ' ' +
    left( right( firstcol,  6 ) ,2 ) + ':' +
    left( right( firstcol,  4 ) ,2 ) + ':' +
    right( firstcol,  2 )
    , 120)
```

For second column:

```
CONVERT( float, right( secondcol, 3 ) ) / 1000
```

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of left function.

Comment: you should cast text to varchar.

Comment: ou should cast text to varchar. substring function can do this work, see @vicdor answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, 
        (SUBSTRING(dateValue, 1, 8) + ' ' + 
         SUBSTRING(dateValue, 9, 2) + ':' + 
         SUBSTRING(dateValue, 11, 2) + ':' + 
         SUBSTRING(dateValue, 13, 2))) as 'dateValue',
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), decimalValue) as 'decimalValue'
FROM text_table
```

Comment: Date conversion work fine but without converting the decimal value, it give me error with that!!

Comment: That's the Decimal Error: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Explicit conversion from data type text to decimal is not allowed.